# Non-Kähler Hermitian homogeneous spaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

I am looking for examples of compact homogeneous space endowed with the structure of a non-Kähler Hermitian manifold.

Comment: The Calabi-Eckmann manifolds $S^{2p+1}\times S^{2q+1)$ are homogenous complex manifolds that are non-Kahler, and they carry homogeneus Hermitian metrics.

Comment: Thanks for the example!